# Restore Python to default on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python-2.7

I am totally aware a question of similar nature is asked before. But the answer there is not doing any good for me.

I have installed python 2.7.6 in addition to system default 2.7.3. And now my system is screwed up completely. Now I want to remove the 2.7.6 and get back to my system default. update-alternatives command on python is not working!

I have installed the 2.7.6 by downloading source and triggering "config, make, sudo make install" commands.

Please help.

Comment: Please include some details about **how** you installed the 2.7.6 version - via a ppa? from source?

Comment: added details. please help.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the developpers add an 'uninstall' target to their Makefile, so you should at first try to do a:

```
sudo make uninstall
```

Then you can force the configuration of the default 2.7.3 by issuing a:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure python
```

Otherwise, maybe you can explain better what you mean by 'my system is screwed up completely'.